# Too many users on my MacPro

Tags: user-accounts, users

I am using a MacBook Pro running macOS Catalina 10.15.5 over the past couple of years I have created three users. I want to have one user. How do I get the files I want into one user from the three users.

How do I know who is the superuser?

Answer (score 0):

macOS doesn't use or really need the superuser, or root, account [& in fact it is disabled by default & enabling it is not recommended].

Any admin can do any task, so long as they have not been specifically removed from the sudoers list [This is unlikely on anything but a corporate Mac]

Let's assume you just want to move each user's Documents folder contents to one single user; this can be done 2 [or 3] ways…

1. Log in to each user individually, move all documents to the Shared folder at `/Users/Shared`
2. Add yourself as a read/write user by adding an ACL - Get Info on each of the other users' home folders, unlock the padlock bottom right, click the + button at the bottom. Add yourself with read/write privileges, then click the Gear icon & 'Apply to enclosed items.
   You can then use these folders as if they were your own & move data from them to your own structure.

Either way, once you're certain you've got all the needed data, you can delete the old accounts.

The potential 3rd way - as you remove an account you will be asked what you want to do with that user's data. You could save it at this point, but personally I prefer the other two methods, as you get more chance to have a look around & see if you missed anything.